# Trying to test new process and getting "Error Occurred During Flow" message

Tags: process-builder

This is the error detail: "REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING: Attempted to add a campaign member where either the member id 'null' or the campaign id '70136000000hLaA' is null."

What I am trying to accomplish is automatically adding a lead to a campaign on create based on certain criteria:[image]

Then I have this action to create a campaign member with the campaign ID and status:[image]

The error seems to say that the campaign member ID is missing, but the campaign member doesn't exist yet. That's what I'm trying to create with this process. What else do I need to include in my action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the CampaignMember.LeadOrContactId to the Lead Id.

Comment: It worked, thanks so much! I added the Lead ID > Reference > [Lead].Id field value to my Create a Record action, and my test was successful.